# dynamically add another item using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have item `<ie:menuitem` on the page  with `id=zz15_Upload`. I want add another `<ie:menuitem` after `</ie:menuitem>` tag and but change (add) on `onMenuClick="window.location = 'Allsame add extra at end of the string &amp;MultipleUpload=1';"`

I want to do this with jQuery. Please help on this.

**Code:**

```
 <ie:menuitem id="zz15_Upload" type="option" iconSrc="/_layouts/images/MenuUploadDocument.gif" 
onMenuClick="window.location = '/CR/ttt/_layouts/Upload.aspx?    List=%7BF6047376%2D0318%2D4A50%2DA290%2D7EAF74A23C4E%7D&amp;RootFolder=%2FCR%2Fttt%2FShared%20Documents&amp;Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftestqa%2Este%2Eorg%2FCR%2Fttt%2FShared%20Documents%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx';" 
text="Upload Document" description="Upload a document from your computer to this library." menuGroupId="2147483647"></ie:menuitem>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I tried to find menuitem with id. But not create new menuitem after </ie:menuitem>. I am newbie to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in you onMenuClick event

```
// create menuitem first
var menuitem = ...;

$('#zz15_Upload').after(menuitem);
```

Hope this works. Your question is somewhat vague...

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started,its a trivial task which is usually not asked on forums...

http://api.jquery.com/append/
http://api.jquery.com/add/
http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var clonedObj= $("#zz15_Upload").clone();
divname.append(clonedObj);
```